# Dalli::DalliError: Response error 130: Out of memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, dalli

```
Dalli::DalliError: Response error 130: Out of memory
from /bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.7.0/lib/dalli/server.rb:496:in cas_response' from /bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.7.0/lib/dalli/server.rb:275:inblock in set'
from /bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.7.0/lib/dalli/server.rb:459:in guard_max_value' from /bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.7.0/lib/dalli/server.rb:272:inset'
from /bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.7.0/lib/dalli/server.rb:60:in request' from /bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.7.0/lib/dalli/options.rb:18:inblock in request'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in mon_synchronize' from /bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.7.0/lib/dalli/options.rb:17:inrequest'
from /bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.7.0/lib/dalli/client.rb:323:in perform' from /bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.7.0/lib/dalli/client.rb:103:inset'
from (irb):13
from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `'
```

Can some one explain this error ? i see there is lot of empty space in memcache but still i am getting this error for few keys .

Comment: It appears that perhaps the payload of some of the values are exceeding the `:value_max_bytes` option. See: https://github.com/mperham/dalli/blob/master/lib/dalli/server.rb#L22

Comment: but when i try the same value with different key it succeeds.

Comment: Then perhaps the problem is with the key length/size? How big is the actual key? Are there any multi-byte characters in the key? Here is a reference saying that the key size can be up to 250 chars: https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt#L47

Comment: key size is pretty small around 30 characters and it doesn't have whitespaces and same key got set after 100's of retries..

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error briefly when memcached server was hanging. Until someone comes up with a more decisive answer, restart memcached and look at its configuration. Maybe the "-m" argument is trying to use more memory than the server has available.

There's [some indication here](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-19961?gerritIssueStatus=All) it might be caused by an earlier memcached bug, so ensure you're up to date.